# How to limit a Data View Web Part to 1 Item Per (Most Recent)?

Tags: data-view-web-part, filter

I have a DVWP that I need to set up a complex filter on.

It WAS all set - grouped by category field, sorted by item title, then filtered on 2 other fields (year & quarter). Then I was given another requirement - that there might be multiple items per the same year and quarter, and I need to display only the most "recent". I can't make the assumption that the users are actually going to create them in order, so I'll need to use the extra "month" field (numeric, 1-12, sometimes null where appropriate).

Is there a way to say "Display all of the items for this year+quarter combination, but sort additionally by the Month field and leave out any duplicates"?

I should note that the month field would not actually be displayed on this DVWP.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, could you post the answer?

Comment: I don't believe so. The project has gone stale due to time constraints so I haven't looked into it too much further.

Comment: This can be done with a little XPath trickery, but I think I'd need to see the schema of your results set, but hard to visualise in the question as it is for now.

Comment: Did you considered building calculated columns beforehand, that could extract month, or quarter and use instead those columns for sorting and grouping?

Answer (score 1):

I might take a look at calculating the year, quarter, and month from one date field. After that, it's just a matter of sorting and putting an item limit of "1" on the DVWP.

- Filter = Display this year/quarter
- Sort = By Month, Descending
- Item Limit = Display only 1

If you just need the most recent, "duplicates" is irrelevant.

- Calculate Month: =MONTH([Date Field])
- Calculate Year: =YEAR([Date Field])
- Calculate Quarter: =IF(AND(MONTH([Date Field])>=1,(MONTH([Date Field])<4)),"1",IF(AND(MONTH([Date Field])>=4,(MONTH([Date Field])<7)),"2",IF(AND(MONTH([Date Field])>=7,(MONTH([Date Field])<10)),"3",IF(AND(MONTH([Date Field])>=10,(MONTH([Date Field])<=12)),"4")))

Answer (score 0):

In the XSL for the web part, use a filter in your XPath.  Like such:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/ListName/Rows/Row[(@Year) = $year_Paramater and (@Month) = $month_Parameter and (not(@MonthYearCom = preceding-sibling::Row/@Model_x0020_Number))]">
```

Then you would have to inject the "year_Parameter" and "month_parameter" into the parameters to compare them.